# What is the measurement grid in the context of strain gauge?

Tags: sensor, physical-design, dimensions

The sensor I am investigating is the 1-LM11 by Omega.

I am looking at the specification at there are two metrics which confuse me, the measurement grid A is 1.5mm while measurement grid B is 2.5mm. This really doesn't make much sense intuitively while looking at the picture

[image]
Dimensions C and D seem slightly more likely with them being 9 and 4.4 respectively. Could someone clarify what the market grid is exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measurement grid is the actual active part of the sensor, the resistance wire that is used to measure deformation. Your picture might be a bit misleading, as it seems your ratios between dimensions are very different from those in the picture, but that's why they give you numbers--so they don't have to make a separate to-scale image of every product in the line.